# Can't push view controller in AppDelegate with TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a TabBarController as a rootViewController for my app. And I'm trying to push view controller when user clicks to notification. But code isn't working. How can I push view controller from AppDelegate without storyboards.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = TabBarController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
    }
```

Comment: Your code is fine. What are you getting now? Are you setting `TabBarController` `viewControllers` properly?

Comment: You forgot to set a navigation controller to `TabBarController.viewControllers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to embed the tab inside a navigation

```
 let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabBarController())
 nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
 window?.rootViewController = nav
```

Then inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

```
if let nav = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
    nav.pushViewController(////
}
```

to show nav inside the vc `viewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

Comment: Actually with this code I can push the ViewController but, there is no navigationBar because we disabled it at beginning of the code. What we can we do?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

You should not embed UITabBarController in a UINavigationController (as written in [Apple Documentation init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621858-init) and [push](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller)). However, it's working.

The **correct solution** is to use UINavigationController as tabs in UITabBarController:

```
let tabBarController = TabBarController()
tabBarController.viewControllers = [UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1), UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)]
window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

and then push to them:

```
let navigationController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
navigationController?.pushViewController(notificationViewController)
```

Or you can create a new view controller and settng it as a rootViewController of window:

```
window?.rootViewController = notificationViewController
```

But this requires more navigation code to setting back tabBarController after dismissing notification etc.